# How to URLDecode in c# .Net, but exclude some characters?

Tags: c#, .net, urldecode

I want to urldecode, except for the `%20` character.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered doing a string replace after decoding? For example

```
string decoded = HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode(input).Replace(" ", "%20");
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work for me

Comment: Could you give more information on how the results differed from what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

use method `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myEncodedString, myWriter);`

Comment: I am looking for decode url so not sure on how to use this method